# unicode_literals and StringIO and the right way to do things

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unicode

Yes, another rambling unicode question.

I have a code snippet:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
from lxml import etree

class Review(object):
    def __init__(self, site_name):
        self.parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        # other things

     def get_root(self, url):
        # snip snip
        resp = requests.get(url)
        html = resp.text
        root = etree.parse(StringIO(html), self.parser)
        return root
```

That works.

In Python 3, that would be something like:

```
from urllib import request
# stuff to detect encoding of page
response = request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read().decode(detected_encoding)
root = etree.parse(StringIO(self.html_doc), self.parser)
```

With a lot of ugly code to handle when the page's declared encoding isn't its actual encoding.

My issue is that unicode_literals is essentially voodoo to me,  I am embarrassed of my ignorance.  Why does `root = etree.parse(StringIO(html), self.parser)` magically work *most* of the time with unicode_literals imported and what is the actual right thing to do in python 2.7?

For example, I have this construct in some Django code I am fixing now :

```
stuff = StringIO(unicode(request.body))
```

And that is just bad and wrong.  But I can't explain why it is bad and wrong except to say that it breaks on *many* encodings that are *not* utf-8

I get that strings are, well, strings with encoding in python 3, ascii in python 2.7.  I get that StringIO lets me treat a string like a buffer.  And I know that `stuff = StringIO(unicode(request.body))`, would sorta/kinda work with unicode_literals imported, but I don't know why which means I don't know the right thing to do to avoid writing a lot of ugly code to detect the encoding of Django's request.body, which is why I am posting this.

tl;dr

What is unicode_literals in python 2.7, would it fix a Django error in `stuff = StringIO(unicode(request.body))`, what would be the side effects?

Much thanks

Comment: Your fundamental misconception is that strings are "strings with encoding" in Python 3. No. Strings are *unicode*, and don't have an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The unicode literals will not affect code like `StringIO(unicode(request.body))`. All it does is change the type of literal strings when you don't use a prefix in Python 2.

Without unicode literals

```
u'y'  # unicode string
b'z'  # byte string
'x'  # byte string
```

With unicode literals

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
u'y'  # unicode string
b'z'  # byte string
'x'  # *unicode* string
```

When you use unicode literals, you have the same behaviour as Python 3.3+ (you couldn't use `u''` in Python 3.0 to 3.2).

The correct way to convert `request.body` from a byte string to a unicode string is to specify the encoding when converting from a byte string to unicode.

```
stuff = StringIO(body.decode('utf-8'))
```

If the encoding is not utf-8, then change the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, clearer.

what if that body.decode throws and UnicodeDecode error?  Do I keep trying other encodings?

Comment: Ideally you should know the encoding, and not have to try multiple encodings. If you are using `requests` to do `resp = requests.get(url)`, then you should be able to get the encoding with `resp.encoding`. If you don't know the encoding, then I'm not sure what the best approach to decode the bytestring would be. If you simply try different encodings until one works, then you might get silent errors.

Comment: in this case the request is coming from some API endpoint, I have no control over what the client app's encoding is.